# Display Ant options, properties specified in invocation

Tags: ant

I have an Ant buildfile (build.xml) which is called by some application. I would like to know exactly what kind of properties are used to invoke Ant. Therefore I would like to modify the build.xml file to display all properties specified in the call, e.g.:

```
ant aTarget -Dxslt.parser=SAXON  -Dbasedir=aFolder
```

would display list as below

```
- target: aTarget
- xslt.parser = SAXON
- basedir=aFolder
```

Please note that I do not know exactly what is being using to invoke Ant. Therefore, I need to use some sort of a loop get all properties, options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing that comes to mind is to place a line like:

```
<echo message="Ant invocation is '${sun.java.command}'"  />
```

In the buildfile outside of any target.  It'll look something like:

```
% ant aTarget -Dx=y

[echo] ant invocation is: 'org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp . aTarget -Dx=y'
```

It shows you what was passed to the Ant Launcher, which might will likely be a little more than what was passed to the ant wrapper script, but should do.

I would avoid trying to parse the line, as you say, you don't know what might be there, and it could quickly get complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`<echoproperties>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html):

```
<property name="in.file.prop" value="value2"/>
<echoproperties/>
```

`in.file.prop` and its value will be printed. However, over 60 other properties will be printed as well including properties built into Ant.

You can save the results of `<echoproperties>` to a file and then filter that file with something like a [`<linecontains>` filter](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#linecontains).